# Capture a frame (image) from a video playing in a QT GUI

Tags: c++, qt, video

I have written a simple video player GUI code in QT. The GUI allows the user to browse the local files and select a video for playing in the GUI. The GUI also has options for 'play', 'pause' and 'stop' to apply to the video selected.

I want to add another button 'Capture', that captures the current frame of the video that is being played, and displays this captured image next to the video (The video should should get paused at this point).
I looked into the documentation of QT, specifically:     [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html#working-with-low-level-video-frames) and [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html#details).    But I am still not able to understand how to implement this in my case.

Kindly guide.

My code so far is as follows:

```
#include "qtwidgetsapplication4.h"
#include <iostream>

QtWidgetsApplication4::QtWidgetsApplication4(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    vw = new QVideoWidget(this);
    player->setVideoOutput(vw);
    this->setCentralWidget(vw);
}

void QtWidgetsApplication4::on_actionOpen_triggered() {
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open a File", "", "Video File (*.*)");
    on_actionStop_triggered();

    player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename));
    on_actionPlay_triggered();
    qDebug("Error Message in actionOpen");
    qDebug()<<player->mediaStatus();
}

void QtWidgetsApplication4::on_actionPlay_triggered() {
    player->play();
    ui.statusBar->showMessage("Playing");
    qDebug("Error Message in actionPlay");
    qDebug() << player->mediaStatus();
}

void QtWidgetsApplication4::on_actionPause_triggered() {
    player->pause();
    ui.statusBar->showMessage("Paused...");
    qDebug("Error Message in actionPause");
    qDebug() << player->mediaStatus(); 
}

void QtWidgetsApplication4::on_actionStop_triggered() {
    player->stop();
    ui.statusBar->showMessage("Stopped");
    qDebug("Error Message in actionStop");
    qDebug() << player->mediaStatus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QVideoProbe` to capture `QVideoFrame`. Instantiate and connect `videoFrameProbed` signal to your slot before pausing video. Convert `QVideoFrame` to `QImage` in this slot using frame data.

```cpp
QImage::Format imageFormat = QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(frame.pixelFormat());
QImage image(frame.bits(), frame.width(), frame.height(), imageFormat);
```

Take a look at [player example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/examples/multimediawidgets/player/player.cpp?h=v5.12.12) for reference. It uses `QVideoProbe` to calculate histogram of current frame.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A follow-up question: So, in my case the connect function will be something like this? 
`connect(m_audioProbe, &QAudioProbe::audioBufferProbed(QVideoFrame), ui->captureButton, on_captureButton_clicked(QVideoFrame));`

And then I define the on_captureButton_clicked slot to display the frame in a label.

Is this the correct approaach?

Comment: I just realized that I am using Qt 6.3, which does not have QVideoProbe anymore. 
It has QVideoSink instead that looks similar. Could you give me an example to show how to use QVideoSink for this purpose?